# linux /proc/<pid>/exe & valgrind

Tags: linux, valgrind

As per the man page /proc/pid/exe is a symlink containing the actual path of the executed command..

when I run valgrind on my program, I see that */proc/pid/exe* points to */usr/lib64/valgrind/amd64-linux/memcheck*

```
lnx-host> which valgrind
/usr/bin/valgrind
```

Any idea why /proc/pid/exe points to usr/lib64/valgrind/amd64-linux/memcheck when I am invoking it as valgrind  ?

In my code I am trying to get the executable name from the pid, and in this case expecting to see valgrind.

Comment: its not, I already checked that.. -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 40020 Apr 13  2006 /usr/bin/valgrind

Comment: the valgrind binary is just a frontend, it'll figure out what to do, and exec the actual tool, in your case memcheck

Comment: @nos, is there anyway I can directly call memcheck then ? The requirement I have is after the program has been invoked, I have to find the program name from pid and I am expecting /proc/pid/exe will match how the user actually invoked it (ofcourse /proc/pid/exe will be the full path)

Comment: @Santhosh: I'm a bit confused, your question is like asking to see `gcc` when invoking it, and being surprised that the backends are called something completely different for the different compilation phases.

Comment: In the general case, no, the user could've invoked a shell script that did various stuff and finally executed somethng, or in this case it the executable itself launches another tool - and the information about what the user invoked is gone. In the special case of the user invoking your own executable directly, /proc/pid/exe would be it.

Answer (score 2):

`memcheck` is the default tool used by Valgrind, unless you tell it to use another of the tools, such as `callgrind`.

Use `--tool=<name>` to specify the tool you want to invoke.

Side-note: is your `/usr/bin/valgrind` also a script just like it is by default? Why not play with that to do what you want to achieve? On my system that invokes first of all `/usr/bin/valgrind.bin` and then the respective (backend) tool (`/usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux`).

---

Relevant output from `strace`:

```
execve("/usr/bin/valgrind", ["valgrind", "./myprog"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0
stat("/home/user/HEAD/myprog", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/valgrind.bin", ["/usr/bin/valgrind.bin", "./myprog"], [/* 39 vars */]) = 0
open("./myprog", O_RDONLY)              = 3
execve("/usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux", ["/usr/bin/valgrind.bin", "./myprog"], [/* 40 vars */]) = 0
getcwd("/home/user/HEAD/myprog", 4095) = 25
open("./myprog", O_RDONLY)              = 3
stat("./myprog", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1886240, ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/fd/3", "/home/user/HEAD/myprog/myprog", 4096) = 31
readlink("/proc/self/fd/3", "/home/user/HEAD/myprog/myprog", 4096) = 31
open("./myprog", O_RDONLY)              = 3
write(1015, "./myprog", 8)              = 8
write(1016, "==23547== Command: ./myprog\n", 28==23547== Command: ./myprog
stat("/home/user/HEAD/myprog/myprog", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1886240, ...}) = 0
open("/home/user/HEAD/myprog/myprog", O_RDONLY) = 3
stat("/home/user/HEAD/myprog/myprog", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1886240, ...}) = 0
open("/home/user/HEAD/myprog/myprog", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/home/user/HEAD/myprog/myprog", O_RDONLY) = 3
readlink("/proc/self/fd/3", "/home/user/HEAD/myprog/myprog", 4096) = 31
getcwd("/home/user/HEAD/myprog", 4096) = 25
lstat("/home/user/HEAD/myprog/myprog", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1886240, ...}) = 0
open("/home/user/HEAD/myprog/datafile", O_RDONLY) = 3
access("/home/user/HEAD/myprog/datafile", F_OK) = 0
open("/home/user/HEAD/myprog/datafile", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/home/user/HEAD/myprog/datafile", O_RDONLY) = 4
```

You'll notice that all `execve` calls are not referring to `./myprog` but instead to the Valgrind wrapper script, the binary and then the backend tool:

```
execve("/usr/bin/valgrind", ["valgrind", "./myprog"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/valgrind.bin", ["/usr/bin/valgrind.bin", "./myprog"], [/* 39 vars */]) = 0
execve("/usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux", ["/usr/bin/valgrind.bin", "./myprog"], [/* 40 vars */]) = 0
```

Comment: I understand that.. but when I call valgrind a.out, /proc/pid/exe is supposed to be a symblink to /usr/bin/valgrind, no ?

Comment: No, it's a symlink to the actual binary that runs. `strace` will shed light on what's going on. After all `memcheck` acts like an emulator and therefore is the program running your program. Btw: in this case your question is not very precise.